# Product Count & Product Image

Tags: magento-1.9

I am installing Marketplace Extension In My website. In Product details Page i need to display seller Product count(How many Product have) and display 3 image of current Seller.

This is my **.phtml**

```
    $active = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/admin_approval_seller_registration/displayproductpage');
    if ($active == 1) { 
        $productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getEntityId();      
        $sellerId      = Mage::registry('current_product')->getSellerId();
        $sellerData    = $this->sellerdisplay($sellerId);
        $showProfile   = $this->sellerprofiledisplay($sellerId);
        if ($showProfile == 1) { 
            $targetPath = 'marketplace/seller/displayseller/id/' . $sellerId;
            $mainUrlRewrite     = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->load($targetPath, 'target_path');
            $getRequestPath     = $mainUrlRewrite->getRequestPath();
            $getRequestPath    = Mage::getUrl($getRequestPath);
            ?>
             <div  class="linker_seller"> 
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Seller'); ?></strong>: 
            <a href='<?php echo $getRequestPath; ?>' class="link_seller"><?php echo $sellerData['store_title']; ?></a>
           <address><?php  $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_countries as $_country) {?>
                <?php if($sellerData['country'] == $_country['value']){?>
                    <?php $sellerCountry = $_country['label'];?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php echo $sellerData['state'].','.$sellerCountry;?></address> 
            <p><?php $description = strip_tags($sellerData['description']);
            $newLengthDescription = strlen( $description);
            $newSubDescription = substr($description, 0, 160);
            if ($newLengthDescription >= 160) {
                $newDescriptionFix = $newSubDescription . "...";
            } else {
                $newDescriptionFix = $description;
            }
            echo $newDescriptionFix; ?>
            <!-- Test -->
<?php
    //Get seller data collection
    /*$seller_collection = $this->getCollection();
    $seller_count = count($seller_collection);*/

    $collection          = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId);
        $collection->addStoreFilter();?>

            <div class="my-account-wrapper"><ul class="mp_all_sellers_container f-left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <?php 
        foreach ($collection as $_seller_collection) {
          $sellerId = $_seller_collection['entity_id'];
          $get_requestPath = Mage::helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getSellerRewriteUrl($sellerId);?>
          <li class="f-left">
            <a class="mp_all_sellers_view" href="<?php echo $get_requestPath; ?>" title="<?php echo $_seller_collection['store_title']; ?>">
            <?php if (strpos($_seller_collection['store_logo'], '.') && $_seller_collection['store_title'] != '') {?>                    
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . "marketplace/resized/" . $_seller_collection['store_logo']; ?>" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> 
            <?php } elseif (!strpos($_seller_collection['store_logo'], '.') && $_seller_collection['store_title'] != '') { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/no-image-thumbnail.png'); ?>" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
            <?php } ?>
            </a>
            <div class="store-title">
                    <a href="<?php echo $get_requestPath; ?>" title="<?php echo $_seller_collection['store_title']; ?>"><?php echo $_seller_collection['store_title']; ?></a>
                    <address><?php $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($_seller_collection['country']);
                        echo $_seller_collection['state'].','."<br/>".$country->getName();?>
                    </address>
<?php //echo $seller_id;?>
            </div>

            <!-- Products for the Sellers -->
                <div class="seller-products">
                <ul id = "seller-product-list" class="products-grid product_snipt f-left">
                    <?php 
                    $sellerProductsCollection = $this->getSellerProducts($sellerId);
                    //echo count($sellerProductsCollection);
                    if (count($sellerProductsCollection) > 0) {
                       $a=1;
                            foreach($sellerProductsCollection as $sellerProduct){
                            if($a%3==0){ 
                                break;
                            }
                                ?>
                            <li class="item <?php if($limit==0):?> bigimage<?php endif;?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo $sellerProduct->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                    <img class="product-image" 
                                    <?php if($limit==0):?>
                                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($sellerProduct, 'thumbnail')->resize(230); ?>" 
                                    <?php else:?>
                                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($sellerProduct, 'thumbnail')->resize(125); ?>" 
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($sellerProduct, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <?php 
                        $a++;}

                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="productslist_bottom">
                <p><span class="totalproducts"><?php echo count($sellerProductsCollection)?></span>
                <span style="font-size:12px">product(s)</span></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $get_requestPath; ?>" title="<?php echo $_seller_collection['store_title']; ?>"><?php echo $this->__("View More")?></a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Products End here -->

         </li>
    <?php } ?> 
    </ul>
    </div>

            <!-- Test -->
            <a href="<?php echo $getRequestPath; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Read More'); ?></a></p>
            <?php 
            $country = str_replace(" ", "+",$sellerData->getCountry());
            $state = str_replace(" ", "+",$sellerData->getState());
            $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="'.$state.'"&sensor=false&region="'.$country.'"';
            $response = file_get_contents($url);
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
            $lat = $long = '';
            if(isset($response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'])){
            $lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
            }
            if(isset($response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])){
            $long = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
            }

            if(!empty($lat) && !empty($long)){
            ?>
           <script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
    <script>
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $long;?>);

    function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });

    marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
            <div id="googleMap"  style="height:150px"></div>

      <?php } 

      /**
       * Ends map functionality
       */
       ?>      

        <?php 

    $displaySeller  = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerreview')->displayReview($sellerId);
    $firstStar     = $secondStar = $thirdStar = $fourthStar = $fifthStar = $advancedTotal = $ratingbar_color = 0;

    /**
     * ITERATING ALL RATINGS
     */ 
    $advancedTotal=0;
    foreach ($displaySeller as $individualStar) {
        $advancedTotal = $advancedTotal + 1;
        if ($individualStar['rating'] == 1) {
            $firstStar = $firstStar + 1;
        } elseif ($individualStar['rating'] == 2) {
            $secondStar = $secondStar + 1;
        } elseif ($individualStar['rating'] == 3) {
            $thirdStar = $thirdStar + 1;
        } elseif ($individualStar['rating'] == 4) {
            $fourthStar = $fourthStar + 1;
        } elseif($individualStar['rating'] == 5) {
            $fifthStar = $fifthStar + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  CALCULATING INDIVIDUAL RATINGS 
     */  

    $advancedOne = $advancedTwo = $advancedThree = $advancedFour = $advancedFive = 0;

    if($advancedTotal >= 1){
    $advancedOne   = ($firstStar / $advancedTotal) * 100;
    $advancedTwo   = ($secondStar / $advancedTotal) * 100;
    $advancedThree = ($thirdStar / $advancedTotal) * 100;
    $advancedFour  = ($fourthStar / $advancedTotal) * 100;
    $advancedFive  = ($fifthStar / $advancedTotal) * 100;
    }

    $positiveFeedBack = ($advancedFour + $advancedFive)/2;
    $totalRatings = $firstStar + $secondStar + $thirdStar + $fourthStar + $fifthStar;
    if($totalRatings != ''){
        echo round($positiveFeedBack,1);
        echo $this->__('% positive feedback. (');
        echo number_format($totalRatings).' ';
        echo $this->__('ratings )');
    }
    ?>      
   <span class="title-sp"><?php $sellerProducts = $this->sellerproduct($sellerId);
   $sellerProducts->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('neq' => $productId));
   $sellerProducts->getSelect()->limit(4);
   ?>
    <?php if(count($sellerProducts) >= 1){ ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Other products from this seller');?>
    <?php foreach($sellerProducts as $_sellerProducts){ ?>
        <?php if($productId != $_sellerProducts['entity_id']){
            $productInfo = Mage::helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getProductInfo($_sellerProducts['entity_id']);
        ?></span> 
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($productInfo, 'small_image')->resize(50); ?>" width="50" height="50" />

    <?php } } ?>

<a href='<?php echo $getRequestPath; ?>' class="btn_more"><?php echo $this->__('More')?></a>
   <?php  } ?>
   </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: as far as i understand this code there is not code related to seller product kindly add related or at-least tables name of seller product.

Comment: I used this $sellerProductsCollection = $this->getSellerProducts($sellerid);<p><span class="totalproducts"><?php echo count($sellerProductsCollection)?></span> it always return 0 only

Comment: did you check current ` $this->getSellerProducts()` function in block and also the variable in code `$sellerId` not `$sellerid`

Comment: Actually this is working code in another phtm so i used but no result

Comment: when you using `$this` it reference to current block check you current have this method or not. enable template/block hint and check if not there add it there.

Comment: Yes I understand How use another phtml code here

Comment: add that code here too so check that..

Comment: Check my updated question i want to same thing in that phtml how i us it

Comment: post this method code `$this->getCollection();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $collection          = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId);
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
```

here is you collection add `count($collection);`

```
              $a=1;
            foreach($collection as $product)
            {  //show you product here
              if($a%3==0) { break;}
             $a++;
              }
```

Comment: then i use same code in this file right

Comment: yes use it anywhere you want to show seller products.

Comment: yes in product details page

Comment: use that but first check you have `$sellerId`.

Comment: apply this code in collection product are loaded just display image of products.

Comment: Okay i check ...

Comment: Where i need to add this collection

Comment: where you want to display it...

Comment: In product details page

Comment: in phtml file add this code and make sure you are getting seller id.

Comment: it shows error Invalid country code:

Comment: in my code there is not country code..

Comment: Yes check my updated Code what mistake i done

Comment: this code don't have seller information only have product of seller. for display use above code..

Comment: Yes i used same code under <!-- Test -->

Comment: Can you please update the answer

Comment: i can give you idea not whole code..

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105964/get-other-seller-ids