# Get Other Seller id's

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get latest 5 Seller id's.
Let us assume i am A Seller in backend i have option other seller block show my profile. In above mention image i update seller id it will display but now i want to automatically get latest 5 seller id Check this url This is my seller method

```
public function updateOtherSellersAction() {

        $fieldId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $otherSellerIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('include_in_othersellers');
        try {
            if ($fieldId) {
                $model = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->load($fieldId, 'seller_id');
                $model->setData ( 'include_in_othersellers', $otherSellerIds)->save ();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception $e ) {
                Mage::getSingleton ( 'adminhtml/session' )->addError ( $e->getMessage () );
        }

    }
```

Here i want to show my other seller id

[image]

**.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateOtherSellersField(button, fieldId)
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/updateOtherSellers') ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { id: fieldId, include_in_othersellers: $(button).previous('input').getValue() },
        complete : alert("Other Sellers Block list has been updated successfully.")
    });
}
</script>
```

**Admin grid**

```
$this->addColumn('include_in_othersellers', array(
                'header'           => Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Include in Other Sellers Block'),
                'align'            => 'center',
                'renderer'         => 'marketplace/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_inline',
                'index'            => 'include_in_othersellers',
        ));


<?php
class Apptha_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Inline
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Input
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $list = $this->OtherSellerList($row);
        $html .= '<input type="text" name="'.$row->getId().'" value = "'.$list.'"/>';
        $html .= '<button onclick="updateOtherSellersField(this, '. $row->getId() .'); return false">' . Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Update') . '</button>';

        return $html;
    }

    public function OtherSellerList(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $id = $row->getData();
        foreach ($id as $_id) {
            $sellerProduct = Mage::helper('marketplace/marketplace')->getSellerCollection($_id);
            return $sellerProduct['include_in_othersellers'];

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Explain properly what do you mean by other seller id ? Other seller id is considering in latest 5 or not.

Comment: this is comma separated values or single value in this column `include_in_othersellers`

Comment: it shows 100,101,102 like this

Comment: you want to retrieve this data?

Comment: Yes i wan to get Latest Seller Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->load($fieldId); // you current seller id

echo $model->getIncludeInOthersellers(); // this will give you desired
```

in renderer add this code for getting values

```
public function OtherSellerList(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $id = $row->getId();
       $otherseller = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->getCollection();
$otherseller->setPageSize(5)
        ;
$otherseller->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
  $sellerid=array();
   foreach($otherseller as $seller)
    {
    $sellerid[]=$seller->getId();
     }

return implode(',',$sellerid);



    }
```

Comment: Where i need to add controllers or phtml

Comment: where you want to display it..

Comment: In backend only so in my question i added image there i want to display

Comment: this field come from form add that field code too..

Comment: You mean Block file or what

Comment: yes block also your controller

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: `marketplace/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_inline` add this block code too

Comment: updated my question

Comment: it is already displaying the id what you required?

Comment: In backend it shows empty textbox only

Comment: It will remove all existing id and it display empty

Comment: it will show other seller ids

Comment: No textbox is empty only

Comment: `echo $id = $row->getId();` and `echo $sellerProduct['include_in_othersellers'];` what are the output of them

Comment: It will dispaly Array736, 851, 859, 864, 655

Comment: this is correct data?

Comment: No this thing we already manually assigned so that it display seller id

Comment: you want to recent seller id?

Comment: Yes recent 5 seller id's

Comment: update the answer try and feedback me..

Comment: now it display seller id's but it show all seller's in same id only 213,212,211,210,209

Comment: this is recent seller id you want. what else you want..

Comment: Sorry bro it's my mistake only i need to add some random 5 id's

Comment: added the code try and feedback me..

Comment: Thank you i need to updated manully or it automatically update (which means update button)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36997/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-learning-magento).

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort collection using seller id in descending order like below

```
$model = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->getCollection()->setOrder('seller_id', 'desc'); 
$model->getSelect()->limit(5);
```

Comment: It's not showing check my updated question

Comment: How to show that text box